# Getting the number of Opportunities for each User

Tags: soql

I want to get the number of Opportunities for each User.

In SQL this would be something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT User.ID FROM USER
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
   SELECT OwnerID FROM Opportunity
       ON User.ID = Opportunity.OwnerId
) GROUP BY USER.ID;
```

Any tips on how I do this in SOQL?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to do something like `SELECT Id, Username, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM User` because the relationship name is unknown (really null when you call describe() on it). I've also experimented with `FROM OwnedOpportunities` etc., no success.

Use Tanuj's or Priyanka's answer depending if you're fine with "if he's not there it means he has 0" or you need to build a full map (and add the entries with UserId => 0 manually).

Comment: can you please provide vf page to display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the list of users who has opportunities and also the users who does not have opportunity, the below code will help!

```
Map<Id,user> Mapuserids = new map<Id,user>([SELECT id from user]);
//list 'lstuserids' holds list of user ids present in the Org
set<id> lstuserids = Mapuserids.keyset();
//find the count of users in the org
system.debug('lstuserids size='+lstuserids.size());
set<id> OppOwnerIds = new set<id>();
list<id> UsersWithNoOpp = new list<id>();
//Using the below aggregate query, find the list of users who has the opportunities and add them in a set
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT Ownerid ownrid, COUNT(Id) countid FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Ownerid];

for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  
{
        OppOwnerIds.add((id)ar.get('ownrid'));
}
//Iterate through the list of users ids and find which users doesn't have an opportunity.

for (Id userid : lstuserids)  
{
   if(!OppOwnerIds.contains(userid))
   {
       UsersWithNoOpp.add(userid);
   }
}
System.debug('list of users size='+UsersWithNoOpp.size());
System.debug('list of users='+UsersWithNoOpp);
```

Comment: So are you saying I can't do an outer join?

Comment: In SOQL we don't have joins..

Answer (score 3):

SELECT Ownerid, COUNT(Id)
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY Ownerid

Comment: This won't give me the Users who have zero opportunities